# use await inside Array.map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, nodemailer

I need to wait for a async function to complete before iterating over the array, the asynchronous function i need to wait to resolve is as follows:

```js
static async sendEmail (from, to, subject, text) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let message = {
                from,
                to,
                subject,
                text
            };
            AMMailing.transporter.sendMail(message, function (err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

This is the code of the way i'm iterating in the array and trying to wait for it to resolve before it iterates again:

```js
static sendEmailInQueue (queue) {
        queue.map(async (person, index) => {
            console.log('sending email to: ', person.email);
            try {
                let success = await AMMailing.sendEmail(AMMailing.message.from, person.email, AMMailing.message.subject, AMMailing.message.text);
                if (success) {
                    console.log('email sent to: ', person.email);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

My problem is: this line `console.log('sending email to: ', person.email);` is executed all times and then the AMMailing.sendEmail() function start to log it's results

this is the output i get in the console:

```
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
sending email to:  matheus.rezende10@gmail.com
{ Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: mail.appmasters.io. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.sgcpanel.com, DNS:sgcpanel.com"
```

Comment: This is most likely not an issue with `async/await`. Have you tried your code with just one user (without mapping - simplest possible implementation) and verified that it works?

Comment: @spicypumpkin yes tried it with single entry and it works as expected, but with multiple it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `map` in your example, it is not mapping anything. You can simply iterate over your array with for-loop to await on each item sequentially. For example:

```
static async sendEmailInQueue (queue) { // async method
  for (let i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
    try {
      // await sequentially
      let success = await AMMailing.sendEmail(/* ... */);
      if (success) {
        console.log('email sent to: ', person.email);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may always use a `.reduce()` with an initial value of `Promise.resove()` and sequence your promisified asynchronous tasks.

Assume that our asynchronous `sendMail(msg,cb)` function sends a mail in 0-250ms. We may promisify it (in case it doesn't return a promise) in our `sendMessages` function and sequence the promises up with `.then()` stages within a `.reduce()`.

```js
function sendMail(msg, cb){
  setTimeout(cb, Math.random()*250, false, "message to: " + msg.to + " is sent");
}

function sendMessages(ms){

  function promisify(fun, ...args){
    return new Promise((v,x) => fun(...args, (err,data) => !!err ? x(err) : v(data)));
  }
  
  ms.reduce((p,m) => p.then(v => promisify(sendMail,m))
                      .then(v => console.log(v)), Promise.resolve());
}

var msgArray = [{from: "x", to: "John@yyz.com", subject: "", text:""},
                {from: "y", to: "Rose@ist.com", subject: "", text:""},
                {from: "z", to: "Mary@saw.com", subject: "", text:""}
               ];
               
sendMessages(msgArray);
```